# Filter Columnview Dblock on Properties or Tags

Tags: org-mode

I have been unable to get the `:match` feature of columnview dblocks to work.  I need it because I want to filter headlines by tags that I used to identify Scrum stories in a particular sprint.  I have basically tried every conceivable version of `:match` such as `:match "Sprint4"`, `:match "Sprint4"`, `:match ":Sprint4:"`, `:match "TAG=\":Sprint4:\""`, and `match: "TAG=\"Sprint4\""`.  Basically, nothing works.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?  I am running Org Mode 9.4.5 on Mac OS X Emacs 27.1.

Here is the offending Org mode text

```
* Scrum Summary
   #+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 3 :id "47B8AC9D-2556-4F6E-AAE1-775731314596" :indent t :maxlevel 4 :match "Sprint4"
   #+TBLNAME: aTable   
   | Status | EPICID | STORYID | TASKID  | Task                     | OWNER | Effort | CLOSED                 | Sprints   |
   |--------+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------|
   |        |        |         |         | Backlog                  |       |     45 |                        |           |
   |--------+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------|
   |        | Epic1  |         |         | \_  Epic on Build It ALL |       |     27 |                        |           |
   |--------+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------|
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story1  |         | \_    Story 1            |       |     12 |                        | :Sprint4: |
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story1  | Task1.1 | \_      Task 1.1         | pablo |      7 |                        | :Sprint4: |
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story1  | Task1.2 | \_      Task 1.2         | john  |      2 |                        | :Sprint4: |
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story1  | Task1.3 | \_      Task 1.3         | pablo |      3 |                        | :Sprint4: |
   |--------+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------|
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story2  |         | \_    Story 2            |       |     15 |                        | :Sprint3: |
   | DONE   | Epic1  | Story2  | Task2.1 | \_      Task 2.1         | pablo |      4 | [2020-12-25 Fri 21:20] | :Sprint3: |
   | DONE   | Epic1  | Story2  | Task2.2 | \_      Task 2.2         | pablo |      5 | [2020-12-22 Tue 01:00] | :Sprint3: |
   | DONE   | Epic1  | Story2  | Task2.3 | \_      Task 2.3         | john  |      6 | [2020-12-25 Fri 21:21] | :Sprint3: |
   |--------+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------|
   |        | Epic1  |         |         | \_  Epic to Run          |       |     18 |                        |           |
   |--------+--------+---------+---------+--------------------------+-------+--------+------------------------+-----------|
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story3  |         | \_    Story 3            |       |     18 |                        |           |
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story3  | Task3.1 | \_      Task 3.1         | pablo |     10 |                        |           |
   | TODO   | Epic1  | Story3  | Task3.2 | \_      Task 3.2         | pablo |      8 |                        |           |
   #+END:
* Backlog
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COLUMNS:  %TODO(Status) %EPICID %STORYID %TASKID %30ITEM(Task) %OWNER %Effort{+} %CLOSED %Alltags(Sprints)
  :Owner_ALL: pablo john
  :EPICID_ALL: Epic1 Epic2
  :ID:       47B8AC9D-2556-4F6E-AAE1-775731314596
  :END:    
** Epic on Build It ALL
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EPICID:   Epic1
   :END:
*** TODO Story 1                                                    :Sprint4:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :STORYID:  Story1
    :END:
**** TODO Task 1.1
     :PROPERTIES:
     :OWNER:    pablo
     :TASKID:   Task1.1
     :END:
***** [2021-05-08 Sat]
      :PROPERTIES:
      :EFFORT:   3
      :END:
***** [2021-05-08 Sat]
      :PROPERTIES:
      :EFFORT:   4
      :END:
**** TODO Task 1.2
     :PROPERTIES:
     :OWNER:    john
     :EFFORT:   2
     :TASKID:   Task1.2
     :END:
**** TODO Task 1.3
     :PROPERTIES:
     :OWNER:    pablo
     :EFFORT:   3
     :TASKID:   Task1.3
     :END:
*** TODO Story 2                                                    :Sprint3:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :STORYID:  Story2
    :END:
**** DONE Task 2.1
     CLOSED: [2020-12-25 Fri 21:20]
     :PROPERTIES:
     :OWNER:    pablo
     :EFFORT:   4
     :TASKID:   Task2.1
     :END:
**** DONE Task 2.2
     CLOSED: [2020-12-22 Tue 01:00]
     :PROPERTIES:
     :EFFORT:   5
     :TASKID:   Task2.2
     :OWNER:    pablo
     :END:
     :LOGBOOK:
     - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-12-22 Tue 01:00]
     - State "TODO"       from              [2020-12-20 Sun 19:46]
     :END:
**** DONE Task 2.3
     CLOSED: [2020-12-25 Fri 21:21]
     :PROPERTIES:
     :OWNER:    john
     :EFFORT:   6
     :TASKID:   Task2.3
     :END:
** Epic to Run
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EPICID:   Epic1
   :END:
*** TODO Story 3
    :PROPERTIES:
    :STORYID:  Story3
    :END:
**** TODO Task 3.1
     :PROPERTIES:
     :OWNER:    pablo
     :EFFORT:   10
     :TASKID:   Task3.1
     :END:
     :LOGBOOK:
     - State "TODO"       from              [2020-12-21 Mon 00:08]
     :END:
**** TODO Task 3.2
     :PROPERTIES:
     :TASKID:   Task3.2
     :OWNER:    pablo
     :EFFORT:   8
     :END:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug: the code cannot deal with both `maxlevel` and `match` set. You get `maxlevel` if it's set (`match` is disregarded in that case); you'll  only get `match` if it is set and `maxlevel` is *not* set.

Here's a workaround while waiting for the bug fix:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 3 :id "47B8AC9D-2556-4F6E-AAE1-775731314596" :indent t :match "Sprint4+LEVEL<=4"
...
```

IOW, you just pass a `:match` argument that incorporates the `:maxlevel` restriction that you want, without using the `:maxlevel` argument.

In the meantime, I'll send a patch to the mailing list and we'll see how it goes. For the record, here's my proposed patch:

```el
diff --git a/lisp/org-colview.el b/lisp/org-colview.el
index 2e1c29a99..7144308ff 100644
--- a/lisp/org-colview.el
+++ b/lisp/org-colview.el
@@ -1398,8 +1398,9 @@ other rows.  Each row is a list of fields, as strings, or
                  (org-get-tags))))
         (push (cons (org-reduced-level (org-current-level)) (nreverse row))
           table)))))
-     (or (and maxlevel (format "LEVEL<=%d" maxlevel))
-        (and match match))
+     (if match
+         (concat match (and maxlevel (format "+LEVEL<=%d" maxlevel)))
+       (and maxlevel (format "LEVEL<=%d" maxlevel)))
      (and local 'tree)
      'archive 'comment)
     (org-columns-quit)
```

EDIT: The bug report and patch is [here](https://orgmode.org/list/87h7h0w5nz.fsf@alphaville.usersys.redhat.com/T/#u)

EDIT: The patch has been merged into the master branch (see [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/1690fbd88f4d55dc0e3c3af44f9fec534e75b601)) but has not been merged into the `maint` branch, so it will not be available until the next major release of Org mode.

Comment: Thanks much NickD@.  The workaround will do for now.